# How to fill NaN only in numeric variables if that variable in on list in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data, numeric, fillna

I have Pandas DataFrame like below:

data types:

- COL1 - numeric
- COL2 - object
- COL3 - numeric

TABLE 1

```
COL1 | COL2 | COL3 
-----|------|------
123  | AAA  | 99
NaN  | ABC  | 1
111  | NaN  | NaN
...  | ...  | ...
```

And I have also list of variables like that: `my_list = ["COL1", "COL8", "COL15"]`

And I need to fill NaN by 0 under below conditions:

- if some column from TABLE 1 is numeric
- if some column from TABLE 1 has NaN
- if some column From TABLE 1 is on my_list

So, I need something like below as an output, because only COL1 meet all above requirements:

```
COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4
-----|------|------|-------
123  | AAA  | 99   | XC
0    | ABC  | 1    | XB
111  | NaN  | NaN  | XA
...  | ...  | ...  | ...
```

How can I do that in Python Pandas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`Index.intersection`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html) and [`select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) to select the columns in which to [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html), then [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
df.update(df[df.columns.intersection(my_list)].select_dtypes('number').fillna(0))
```